# Some html code and output not showing on browser?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a profile page for users. I have created a form and some fields in it. But whatever part code has been written under the  section is not showing on the browser. I tried to inspect the elements, but the code written under the  section is not showing on the browser.

```css
.profile-page {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f4f5fa;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px gray;
}

.profile-heading {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #0b2b88;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.profile-details {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.input-field {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.form-heading {
  width: 30%;
}

.form-input {
  width: 30%;
}

.form-input input {
  border: none;
}

.form-button {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.form-button button {
  background-color: #0b2b88;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.edit-button {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/96c1212185.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="profile-page">
  <div class="profile-heading">
    <h3>Profile Details</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="profile-details">
    <form class="profile-form">
      <div class="input-field">

        <div class="form-heading">
          <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-input">
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="ABC" class="form-input-field" readonly />
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="input-field">
        <div class="form-heading">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-input">
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="admin@gmail.com" class="form-input-field" readonly/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="input-field">
        <div class="form-heading">
          <label for="country">Country</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-input">
          <select id="country" name="country" class="">
            <option value="---">---</option>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="knxnvknfd">
        <div class="jnsdjjdi">
          <button type="submit" id="edit-button" name="" value="" class="form-input-field">Edit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Typo: You forgot an end tag. Everything after your select is **inside** the select. Use [a validator](https://validator.nu/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select` is not closed

```html
<div class="form-input">
          <select id="country" name="country" class="">
            <option value="---">---</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.